# Java ternary operator with multiple conditions

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I'm fairly new to Java data-structures and I need some assistance to have multiple conditions using ternary operator or if there's much better approach on what I'm trying to do.

Basically, I have a text file that put into a 2D array and splitting each line character by character.

However, I'm having some trouble with *conditional statement* to check specific characters from the line.

Here's my current algorithm to do that.

```
for (int i = 2; i < lines.size() - 1; i++) {
        String floorLine = lines.get(i);
        int j = 0;
        for(char coor : floorLine.toCharArray()) {
              floor[i - 2][j] = (coor == '#') ? 0 : 1;
        }
    }
```

As of now, I'm only checking if there's **#** in line then it will encode as **0** else **1**. However, I would like to have something like this

```
floor[i-2][j] = (coor == '#') ? 0 floor[i-2][j] = (coor == 'X') ? 1 floor[i-2][j] = (coor == 'Z') ? 2 : 3
```

So if I use the normal if else statement, I should have like this

```
if 2d array == ( coor == '#') encode as 0
if 2d array == ( coor == 'X') encode as 1
if 2d array == ( coor == 'Z') encode as 2
else encode as 3
```

Any suggestions or tips will be appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: While it is possible to nest ternary statements in Java, it's generally not done because they can quickly get very difficult to read. Readability trumps brevity. Future you will thank you later on if you don't nest them.

Comment: you should use switch-case instead

Comment: Could you describe what the code is doing, on a higher level? It sort of looks to me like "in entire text replace these characters with these numbers", which unless performance of the function is absolutely critical would work better as `text.replaceAll(char,replaceChar)`

Comment: JonK I agree with that, I'm just wondering if its possible to do it like that way with Ternary Operator.

@Deltharis basically it's like a puzzle inside of the text file that's why I'm mapping them into a 2D array then encode specific characters accordingly. The main goal of this program is to get all possible paths of the puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form of the conditional expression is:

```
condition? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

When they're chained, it looks like this:

```
condition_1 ? value_if_1 : condition_2 ? value_if_2 : value_otherwise
```

So I think you mean:

```
floor[i-2][j] = (coor=='#' ? 0 : coor=='X' ? 1 : coor=='Z' ? 2 : 3);
```

To me, this is simple enough to be perfectly readable, but lots of people argue against this use of conditional operator like this; and if it were any more complicated you would be better off using `if` statements instead.

Java is in the process of introducing [switch expressions](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/325), which would also work well for this case.

Comment: I would fail this in a code review. Something shouldn't be a one-liner just because it can be.

Comment: I guess this might be a good candidate for a [switch expression](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/325), when Java gets those.

Comment: @khelwood Java got those a few days ago ;)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko It'll take my place of work a few years to catch up.

Comment: I actually like this one-liner, I can read it thoroughly and it is the condition that I am looking for. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

May as well throw in how I would write this. Pull the conditional into a new method.

```
floor[i - 2][j] = getNumberForCoor(coor);



private static int getNumberForCoor(char coor) {
    switch (coor) {
        case '#': return 0;
        case 'X': return 1;
        case 'Z': return 2;
        default:  return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: But the thing is, I'm getting the coor from this line:
`for(char coor : floorLine.toCharArray())`
How would I get the coor from floorLine with this?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the ternary expression chain I see two alternatives:

- A precalculated mapping from the char to an int.
- If the result is a consecutive numbering 0, 1, 2, ... then the index from the char in a string is usable.

So

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put('#', 0);
map.put('X', 1);
map.put('!', 2);

String enc = "#X!";

for (int i = 2; i < lines.size() - 1; i++) {
    String floorLine = lines.get(i);
    int j = 0;
    for(char coor : floorLine.toCharArray()) {
          floor[i - 2][j] = coor == '#' ? 0
                 : coor == 'X' ? 1
                 : coor == '!' ? 2
                 : 3;

          floor[i - 2][j] = map.getOrDefault(coor, 3);

          int e = enc.indexOf(coor);
          floor[i - 2][j] = e == -1 ? 3 : e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could put your replacements in a map.

```
static Map<Character, Integer> encodings = new HashMap<>();

static {
    // static initializer, a way to populate the map easily, not the only way
    encodings.put('#', 0);
    encodings.put('X', 1);
    encodings.put('Z', 2);
}

//and in your function
floor[i-2][j] = encodings.getOrDefault(coor, 3);
```

Comment: My issue with this is that the integer value 3 may exist far away from the rest of the values. If I decide that the values should be 1-indexed then it would be very easy to forget to change the default to 4.